# What are the main threats and quickfixes for a client(Mobile App) and Server model

Tags: asp.net, .net, facebook, azure, oauth

I'm writing a basic API for a mobile app that I'm creating, it involves creating an Account (FB OAuth), a few HTTP POSTs, a few HTTP GETs and that's about it,

The server stores a few things in a MYSQL instance, really only about 5 tables, may need to scale later on.

I'm using MVC5 with Windows Azure as my hosting.

I'm a bit of a one man developer and usually code for front end, so I don't have a lot of time to really deal with anything that isn't absolutely necessary, so I guess I'd be interested to get some 101 heads up for those that deal with medium traffic data service APIs, namely with the Azure MVC .net framework.

I most want to know if using a FB Token + perhaps a shared secret is enough for feeling sure that my server doesn't become compromised.